# How to align td text to the top of visible part of cell?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My table consists of two column: name of object and object. Name is just one word. Object can occupy several screens. I want to hold name on top of visible part of its cell. In this case when user scrolls page down he can see name of the object until the object is hidden. How can I do this? Are there plugins to do so?

Comment: You'd need to hook into the scroll event and calculate the scroll-position of the screen and absolutely-position the name tag. While not difficult, it is not trivial. You may want to look up "floating table header". http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=floating+table+header

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only a couple lines of jQuery. http://jsfiddle.net/VuRvs/
Attach a handler to the window scroll event, find your "sticky" heading, position them based on the current scroll position make sure they stay inside of their parent element (the TD).

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var y = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop;
    $(".sticky").each(function() {
        var elm = $(this);
        var td = elm.parent("td");
        var tdTop = td.offset().top;
        var tdBot = tdTop + td.height() - elm.outerHeight();
        if(y <= tdBot && y >= tdTop) {
            // set a placeholder
            if(td.children().length == 1)
                td.append(elm.clone().removeClass("sticky").css("visibility", "hidden"));
            elm.css("position", "absolute");
            elm.css("top", y + "px");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: @freopen - This was just a rough example, if you're users wanted to print out these tables, you'll run into issues with the absolutely positioning. If printing becomes an issue I'd set up 2 classes "sticky" and "notsticky" the place holder (cloned element) will have the "notsticky" class and in the print media CSS notsticky would be set to visible and sticky would be set to display: none

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing, is a persistant header, or a freeze pane like Excel.

Check [this link](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/), it's nicelly explained.